# how do i get mp4 meta data with python

Tags: python, metadata

**what I want to do**

i want to get the comments from a mp4 files.
i need to get the comments of multiple files(over 500) in iether a file or as a varible to use later in a script.

**what I've tried**

i've searched google and stack overflow and i cant find anything.
iev tried these packages:

ffmpeg

tagpy

mutagen

**the problem**

all the packages and answers ive tried are either outdated or dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to install tools other than python then consider installing [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) and then try install and use [PyExifTool](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/).